# Mysql Update field with max value between 2 other fields

Tags: mysql, max

In my mysql table i have 3 fields: weight, gweight, volweight

gweight and volweight have different values, i'd like to update weight with max value between gweight and volweight.
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean max value between? Do you mean of the two values gweight and volweight grab the larger of the two?

Comment: yes! i need it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET weight=GREATEST(gweight,volweight);
```

Warning this will update every row.

See the manual page for [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest).

Other things to note:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    col1 int null,
    col2 int null,
    col3 int null
);

INSERT xxx2(col1,col2) values (null,1),(1,2);

UPDATE xxx2
SET col3=GREATEST(col1,col2);
SELECT * FROM xxx2;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | NULL |    1 | NULL |
|  2 |    1 |    2 |    2 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

So NULL in a column does not make for a happy `GREATEST()`. If your columns are not NULLABLE then there is no worry for the above and you can ignore the below fix:

```
TRUNCATE xxx2;
INSERT xxx2(col1,col2) values (null,1),(1,2);

UPDATE xxx2
SET col3=GREATEST(COALESCE(col1,0),COALESCE(col2,0));
SELECT * FROM xxx2;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | NULL |    1 |    1 |
|  2 |    1 |    2 |    2 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

So [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) would fix NULL issues.